# Installing PGI Fortran on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, fortran

I need to install PGI Fortran on Ubuntu 20.04. The online [PGI documentation](https://www.pgroup.com/resources/docs/20.4/x86/pgi-install-guide/index.htm) to do that seems outdated and I am also having a hard time following it as I am new to Ubuntu. Please see if it can still be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use NVHPC (https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-hpc-sdk-downloads), which is the next generation of compilers substituting the old PGI ones.

Comment: Is there a sudo apt install way to install this?

Comment: I usually install from source but, if you want to use apt, there should be also a deb file.